# how to fix "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'MBMovingGround?' with no arguments" error in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm making a Swift game but I have very limited coding experience
I'm following a guide on youtube to get started and get basic understanding
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Q18FYgLYYo&list=PL1YTxp2xLtqSiBhoAiaImXFcjAAxvo1es&index=4

I have tried what Xcode is suggesting but I am stuck on this error:
"Cannot invoke initializer for type 'MBMovingGround?' with no arguments"

here is a part of my "GameScene.swift" File

```
var movingGround = MBMovingGround?()

override func didMove (to view: SKView) {
    backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 159.0/255.0, green: 201.0/255.0, blue: 244.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    movingGround = MBMovingGround(size: CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 20))
    movingGround.position = CGPoint(x: 0,y: view.frame.size.height/2)
    addChild(movingGround)
}

func TouchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    movingGround.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `()` from here `var movingGround = MBMovingGround?()` and declare it this way `var movingGround = MBMovingGround?`.
Your class `MBMovingGround` don't have an initializer with no arguments parameters, so you can't use an empty initializer with no parameters like you were doing with `()`.

Otherwise you can just initialize it with an argument with zero size:

`var movingGround = MBMovingGround(size: .zero)`

Comment: Thank you for your response I had tried your solution before but Xcode now tells me "Expected member name or constructor call after type name"

Comment: I revised my answer with a second option

Comment: yes! it works thank you very much, it's awesome helps me a lot

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear:

You have to use an initializer with arguments like `MBMovingGround(size:)`, but you must **not** use the default initializer `MBMovingGround()`

In this case **declare** the variable and initialize it later

```
var movingGround : MBMovingGround?
```

or – still better – initialize it non-optional with an *empty* value

```
var movingGround = MBMovingGround(size: .zero)
```

Declaring an optional with a default value make no sense anyway.